# Error en TypeScript (Interface)

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

Estoy viendo como funciona lo de las interfaces en **typescript** pero me da este problema y al buscar en Internet solo he visto un foro donde dicen que lo tienen que arreglar en una actualización. Alguien sabría como se puede solucionar?

> 'setColor', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an
>   'any' return type.

```
//INTERFACE  (base de las clases)
interface CamisetaBase{
    setColor(color);
    getColor()

}

//CLASE (molde del objeto)           EL NOMBRE DE LA CLASE SIEMPRE ES EL MISMO QUE EL FICHERO
class Camiseta implements CamisetaBase{

//PROPIEDADES (características del objeto)
    public color:string;
    public modelo:string;
    public marca:string;
    public talla:string;
    public precio:number;
//MÉTODOS (funciones o acciones del objeto)
    constructor(color:string,modelo:string,marca:string,talla:string,precio:number){
        this.color=color;
        this.modelo=modelo;
        this.marca=marca;
        this.talla=talla;
        this.precio=precio;
    }
    public setColor(color:string){
        this.color=color
    }

    public getColor(color:string){
        return this.color
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

La falla se presenta porque no tienes definido los tipos de valores de retorno y tipos de valores recibidos en tu función.
Utiliza esto:

```
interface CamisetaBase{
    setColor(color : string) : void;
    getColor() : string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como respondió @jojmartinezma, te falta definir los tipos de las funciones de tu interfaz base:

```
interface CamisetaBase{
    setColor(color: string): void;
    getColor(): string

}
```

Si los dejas tal y como están actualmente, la clase que implementa esa interfaz, estaría alterando lo "establecido" desde ahí, que es un tipo `any` por defecto para dichas funciones.

Pero además, te falta acomodar tu función `getColor()` en la clase, ese "getter" no tiene por qué recibir un parámetro, puesto que va a retornar el color que tienes asignado como atributo, sería así:

```
public getColor(): string{
  return this.color;
}
```